# Validate that there is only one row when using iloc[0]

Tags: python, pandas

I have a one row `DataFrame` and convert it to a `Series` like this

```
df.iloc[0]
```

But because this `df` is the result of a query I want to be absolutely sure that there is only 1 row and not more.

From other languages I know methods like `first()` or `one()` which would raise an error if there are `!= 1` rows in the data frame.

I **do not want to check explicit** via `if len(df) != 1:`.
This is waste of code.

Comment: What is the problem with `if len(df)!= 1` or `assert len(df) == 1`?

Comment: Why don't you want to check via `len`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that there is no such possibility to combine *accessing* the first element and also *checking* if it is the only one in the array/list.

Pandas do not offer something like `one()`.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:** Extend pd.DataFrame

AFAIK, there's no such function. You could extend `pd.DataFrame` with this functionality, but working with derived classes may not be suitable for you either.

```py
class DataFrame(pd.DataFrame):
    def one(self):
        if self.shape[0] != 1:
            msg = "Expecting a DataFrame with exactly one row."
            raise RuntimeError(msg)
        else:
            return self.iloc[0]
            # Alternatively:
            return self.squeeze()
```

**Option 2:** Squeeze and assert

Instead of `df.iloc[0]`, you could use [pd.DataFrame.squeeze()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.squeeze.html). It doesn't raise an error if `len(df)!=1`, but you could combine it with an assertion as follows:

```py
data = df.squeeze()
assert isinstance(data, pd.Series)
```

Be aware that the assertion fails if `df.shape == (1,1)` (will be squeezed to scalar).

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to throw an error if there is more than 1 row, just try selecting the second row:

```
try:
    df.iloc[1]
except IndexError:
    print('more than one row!')
```

*NB. I do not see any advantage in doing this compared to checking the length/shape*